# Convert code block to a MVC Razor code block

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
<img src="/Chart/CreateChart?chartType=<%=System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie %>"
                alt="" />
```

What is the equivalent to the above in a MVC Razor code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<img src="/Chart/CreateChart?chartType=@System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie" alt="" />
```